# Using jQuery how can I select a child when also using .closest()?

Tags: jquery, css, class, jquery-selectors, closest

I'm trying to select an element in my html, I'm able to select it using the following...

```
$(".card .card-title > div a span.paragraph-end").css({ background: "linear-gradient(to right,rgba(255,255,255,0)," + $(this).css("background-color") + "" });
```

I started with the above so I could see if it worked, now I'm trying to select just the instance on the page I want to change and not all of them.  So I was able to select the `.card` I want to change using:

```
$(this).closest(".card")
```

But doing

```
$(this).closest(".card .card-title div a span.paragraph-end").css({ background: "linear-gradient(to right,rgba(255,255,255,0)," + $(this).css("background-color") + "" });`
```

didn't work for me.  How can I select a child class after using the closest method?

Comment: @Jeff, `this` is a div that I have set up for the user to click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find the `paragraph-end` element within the current `card` so use `closest()` to locate the `card` then use `.find()` to locate the `paragraph-end` element

```
$(this).closest(".card").find(".card-title div a span.paragraph-end").css({
    background: "linear-gradient(to right,rgba(255,255,255,0)," + $(this).css("background-color") + ""
});
```

Comment: Thanks! worked perfectly!  I had found different methods like `has()` and stuff but none worked.  Not sure how I missed this one I greatly appreciate it!